# Add ul ID in WordPress submenu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, accessibility

I want to add an ID to the submenu  in WordPress that matches the link text of the sibling  like this:

```
<nav id="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#about-us">About Us</a>
            <ul id="about-us" class="sub-menu">
                ...
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have a custom walker that looks like this:

```
class axs_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
   $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

   $class_names = $value = '';

   $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
   $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

   $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
   $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

   $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
   $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

   $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

   $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
   $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
   $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
   $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

   $item_output = $args->before;
   if ( $depth > 0) {
     $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
   } else {
     $item_output .= '<a aria-haspopup="true"'. $attributes .'>';
   }
   $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
   $item_output .= '</a>';
   $item_output .= $args->after;
   $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
 }
 function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
   $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
   $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul ' . $id . ' class="axs-sub-menu">' . "\n";
 }
}
```

So my problem is; how to get the anchor link text as a variable and how to make it URL friendly. (e.g. "About Us" -> "about-us")

And also, for the sibling a do something like this:

```
if ($subMenu){
    <a href="$pleaseHelp">
}
```

**Note:** This is not for styling purposes but for accessibility and usability, to be able to add aria-owns="about-us" and aria-controls="about-us". (Ofc added w/ JavaScript)

Comment: How and where does the About Us come into this HTML: `<a href="#about-us">About Us</a>`? You have not shown in your question, that code is missing.

Comment: I use the regular WordPress function like this `<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'main_menu','container' => 'false','link_before' => '<span>','link_after' => '</span>', 'walker' => new my_custom_li_nav_menu() )); ?>` and the <a> element comes from that menu.

Comment: Well, you need to check where it originally comes from. wp_nav_menu() runs some query and then has an array of objects. One of those objects then has the title and that exact location is meant. You need to dig a bit in there if you want to understand this.

Comment: Is the parent link (about-us) supposed to open the sub-menu and put the focus there? If so, you don't need to use the ID, you could put an onclick on the link and set the focus in the script.

Comment: @AlastairC Yes, the parent link will open a sub-menu. And yes I will use JS to do it. But for screen readers and other assistive technologies the ul mus have an ID so you can hook, aria-expanded, aria-controls, aria-owns and so on.

Comment: I would have thought you can add those IDs dynamically through the script if it is difficult in PHP? Adobe recently open-sourced their main menu code which doesn't appear to need that, and might help here. http://adobe-accessibility.github.io/Accessible-Mega-Menu/

Answer (score 4):

Technically you're looking for the href value (minus the `#` at the beginning) of the last element processed.

I see two ways to obtain it:

1. Extract the last `<a .... >` HTML tag from `$output`, parse it as HTML and get the href value, substring from offset 1 and done. A HTML parser in PHP is Tidy: http://php.net/tidy.parse_string
2. Store the current element with the walker class as a private member from which that information can be obtained from;

   ```
   class My_Walker extends Walker
   {
       private $current;

       ...

       public function start_el(&$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0) {
           $this->current = $object;

           ...                

           # access the right property later in start_lvl (->title is made up)
           $id = sanitize_title_with_dashes($this->current->title); 

           ...
   ```

I can't say if any of those work for you but I think one of the two should do it. In any case you need to learn where you can obtain the original value from that you would like to create the ID from and then think about how to access it or make it available. The private property method in 2. most likely is more stable.

Comment: Sorry, quite new to backend stuff, and not that familiar to the Walker class.. could you be a little more specific? I'll put my walker in full at top.

Comment: Go with 2. and try to implement that. Put the updated code as well (next to your original one) into the question. Then I might take a look.